# Enabling slice expansion on hover in react-apexcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

We are using Pie/Donut Chart in react-apexcharts, I would like to ask you guys if there is a way to enable slice expansion on the hover event.
I can see there is a way to enable slice expansion on click event but seems not for hover event.
Please let me know if you have any solutions.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: is these two solutions on here helpful ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719644/increase-pie-chart-size-onhover-with-highcharts one is for scaling the whole chart on hover, one is for expanding an slice on hover.